# Titanium : can't get the current window in tabbed app

Tags: android, ios, tabs, titanium

I need to get current window in the tabbed application.

I tried with

var win = Ti.UI.currentTab.window();

and with

var win  = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

but get the  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'window' of undefined` error in both cases.

Comment: you should also mention that which structure you are using? commonJS or alloy or traditional?

Comment: hi, I'm using alloy technology

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TabGroup, you can access current window through [activeTab property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-property-activeTab). It's not global function, so you have to have keep reference to TabGroup object in your code:

```
var tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({ tabs: createTabs() });
tabGroup.activeTab.window
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentTab` and `currentWindow` are holdovers from when you could spin off multiple JavaScript contexts from a `Ti.UI.createWindow({ url: 'foo.js' })`. I'd recommend you don't use them.

There are a couple of patterns to choose from when you need to communicate from one part of your app to the UI at another part.

**1st option**: listen for and fire events a la `Ti.App.addEventListener('foo', function(data){})` and `Ti.App.fireEvent('foo', { })`. This decouples the code nicely, so you can move the UI handling code around without changing the firing code.

**2nd option**: expose the UI objects through modules. In your controller, `exports.win = $.win;`.

**3rd option**: set a global object: `Alloy.Globals.win = $.win;`.

Comment: thank you. where should I set a global object if I'm using Alloy. In index.js ? thanks.

Comment: You should set it in the controller that has access to the view which you want to expose.

Answer (score 0):

ok so in alloy framework, we just use $ sign to get all the controls which are created in .xml file...

so if you set id of your window tag in .xml file then you can get current window with below example...

.xml file

```
<Alloy>
   <Window id="win">
   </Window>
</Alloy>
```

.js file

```
var win = $.win
```

so from above code you can get your current window.

Hope you get it.